Is window.requestAnimationFrame() less resource demanding than setInterval() for animations?
Background:
MDN's page on optimizing canvas says:

With animations, use window.requestAnimationFrame() instead of setInterval() .

I'm not sure I know the reason for this. Is it just because requestAnimationFrame will draw the animation more often (e.g. at 60fps)?
If this is the reason, then would setInterval(myAnimFunction, 16.7) produce the same result? (60fps) Or is requestAnimationFrame less resource intensive for rendering animations?
The example provided in this answer (What are the differences between setInterval and requestAnimationFrame?) actually works more smoothly with requestAnimationFrame than setInterval(anim2, 10), so it makes me thing there's something else making requestAnimationFrame better than just the frequency (I think it's because it triggers exactly before repaint). I've included that code below:


window.requestAnimationFrame(anim1);

window.setInterval(anim2, 10);

var a1 = document.getElementById('a1');
var a2 = document.getElementById('a2');
var t2 = 0;

function anim1(t1) {
    a1.style.left = (50 + Math.cos(t1 / 500) * 30) + 'px';
    a1.style.top = (50 + Math.sin(t1 / 500) * 30) + 'px';
    window.requestAnimationFrame(anim1);
}

function anim2() {
    a2.style.left = (100 + Math.cos(t2) * 30) + 'px';
    a2.style.top = (50 + Math.sin(t2) * 30) + 'px';
    t2 += 0.055;
}
div { position: absolute; width: 10px; height: 10px; background: gray; }
<div id="a1"></div><div id="a2"></div>



Another difference between them is that setInterval will keep working even when the browser tab is not focused, whereas requestAnimationFrame will pause. But this might not be what you want, so I wouldn't say it counts as one using less resources than the other.
Question:
Is requestAnimationFrame less resource intensive when drawing animations (and possibly better at rendering animations more smoothly) than setInterval?

In itself, rAF is not less resource demanding, quite on the contrary it will mark your document as being animated and will force it to enter the update the rendering phase even if nothing is done in the callback requiring a graphic update. The advantage of rAF is that it knows when the browser will send the next frame to the compositor. So you can be sure it will be in sync. With setInterval you have to assume a fixed frame rate, and you may very well add or lose frames. So yes it's better to use rAF but it's not as dramatic as some says and no it's not magically "faster" or anything.
